# Layout issue in iPad and iPhone safari browser

Tags: ios, css, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-safari

I am having issue with only iPad and iPhone safari browser. I have attached difference that will show difference between both screen.

In iPad and iPhone safari browser, top of the main container is hidden in the navbar. It's working fine in iPad chrome browser including desktop and android device browser.

[image]

We are using bootstrap v3. Here navbar and container-fluid are having `position:fixed;`

Following are `.main-container` properties,

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
width: 100vw;
```

Not sure how to fix this issue just for iPad and iPhone safari? Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Did you try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width" />` meta tag? It seems like an initial-scale issue.

Comment: @NimitShah, meta tag is already there. But it's just not working in iPhone and iPad safari browser.

Comment: @KomalJariwala: It would be great if you post the piece of code here.. at least html which has main-container class attached and related css.

Comment: Here is my main page HTML including navbar, main-container which is `container-fluid` and footer,

`<div id="any" class="ember-view">
 <div class="">
  <nav>
    ...  
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid static-container">
   <div class="row scroll-container">
    <div class="side-margin">
       ...                
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`

`.side-margin{
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);

}`

Comment: Are you sure you need `position:fixed` for main-container? If not, try removing it.. that might work!

Comment: Also try adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on main-container

Comment: @NimitShah, I can't remove `position:fixed` as we don't want scrollbar for whole screen. I already tried second option, but it's not working. Thanks for all options, I fixed my issue using `top:55px;` which is not best solution, but it seems working temporarily,